# Swift Alamofire, only sends 4 post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, xcode, swift, alamofire

I am trying to develop an app which sends a HTTP POST request to a NodeJS server (on the localhost).  I am using the networking library 'Alamofire' just to try and simplify things.

**My issue arises when** I try and send multiple requests,  I set up a simple button which sends the post request.  When I run the app i can click the button and see that it sends the post requests when I click it, but only for the first 4 button presses/post requests.

It may be possible that my server is not set up correctly and not sending a response back or something along those lines.

I get 4 post's each time i open the app - everytime i close and re open the app i get another 4.

The same goes for when I restart the server.

I have tested the server using a pre-existing app (HTTP utility) and it appears to work fine.

When I use Alamofire i use JSON encoding, could this cause the issue???

Here's my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBAction func postBTN(sender: AnyObject) {
    post(["xx":[10]])

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func post(postParrams: [String : AnyObject]) {
   Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://10.0.0.10:3000", parameters: postParrams, encoding: .JSON)
}

 }
```

UPDATE *** I added the following code below the 'Alamofire.request' to print the response data:

```
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("Validation Successful")
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("the error is", error)
            }


        }
```

The error code that prints is:

```
the error is Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd5a3d0e170 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

From this i gather that the response result is a 'failure' and there are 2 error codes: Code=-1001, CodeKey=-2102

Comment: Try to print the response   `.responseString { response in
            ...
         }`

Comment: i printed the response and receive this:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 

UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8af8f1d600 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork 

Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, 

_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000/, 

NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, 

_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

Comment: -1001 is internet connection problem, did you try to make a request via browser or like that? To check whether the server is responding